# Android google maps v2 custom dilog

Tags: android, google-maps, dialog, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Since now on I cannot get an API key for maps V1, I need to migrate my code to v2. So what I need is when user taps on one pin on the map to show a dialog (that contains the name of the point and a button). If he taps on the button I open a new activity that displays info about that place. I have successfully done this with map overlays that I passed my custom data in the constructor and I have everything I needed. But how can this be done using markers for maps v2? I can't find anything about custom dialogs.

Comment: If you have an app and key for v1, you may still use it. You don't have to "migrate".

Comment: No, for this certificate I do not have a key. It is for a new client and I created a new certificate ( I can't give my previous one ).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to implement `InfoWindow` with a button, as `Google Map` automatically renders all it's content to an image. The only thing you can listen to clicks of is the `InfoWindow` it self.

Here is code for creating the `InfoWindow` and assign an `OnInfoWindowClickListener` there are comment that will explain you the steps.

```
// Setting a custom info window adapter for the google map
        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker args) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker args) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

                // Getting the position from the marker
                clickMarkerLatLng = args.getPosition();

                TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                title.setText(args.getTitle());

                //Setting OnInfoWindowClickListener
                map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {          
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) 
                    {
                        if (SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation!=null)
                        {   
                            if (String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLatitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) &&
                                    String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLongitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This your current location, navigation is not needed.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                FlurryAgent.onEvent("Start navigation window was clicked from daily map");
                                tasksRepository = SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().tasksRepository.getTasksRepository();
                                for (Task tmptask : tasksRepository)
                                {
                                    String tempTaskLat = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude());
                                    String tempTaskLng = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLongtitude());

                                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8));

                                    if (tempTaskLat.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) && tempTaskLng.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                                    {  
                                        task = tmptask;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,RoadDirectionsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra(TasksListActivity.KEY_ID, task.getId());
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your current location could not be found,\nNavigation is not possible.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
                return v;

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom Dialog and the Map itself are two totally separate entities and the development of one does not influence the development of the other.

You'll use the a OnMarkerClickListener ([here the link to the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#marker_click_events)) and whenever you receive that even you'll create your custom dialog just as you used to do before.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a marker using

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos1).title("title").snippet("description"));
```

if you tap on marker, a info window will open, with "Title" and "description", even you can customize this info window by extending InfoWindowAdapter class, and then set that infoWindowAdapter to GoogleMap obj. for more info plz refer below link
[Google Map API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#add_a_marker)